# Is there a way to get the parameters that were passed to a GCP Dataflow job from the CLI/API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have tried the `describe` command listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataflow/jobs/describe) and I don't see the parameters. Is there another command that I should use to get this information, or some other API that would provide it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** - You're missing the `--full` argument to the [`gcloud dataflow jobs describe`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/describe) command.

> **FLAGS**
>
> `--full`
>
> Retrieve the full Job rather than the summary view

### View full job info

If you're using `gcloud` to view the information about the GCP Dataflow job, this command will show the full info (which is actually quite a lot of info) about the job including any parameters that were passed to the job:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs describe JOB_ID --full
```

All the options are under the hierarchy `environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options`

### View all options as JSON

To view all the options passed to the job (which prints actually more than just the command line arguments BTW) as a JSON, you can do:

```
$ gcloud dataflow jobs describe JOB_ID --full --format='json(environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options)'
{
  "environment": {
    "sdkPipelineOptions": {
      "options": {
        "apiRootUrl": "https://dataflow.googleapis.com/",
        "appName": "WordCount",
        "credentialFactoryClass": "com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcpCredentialFactory",
        "dataflowEndpoint": "",
        "enableCloudDebugger": false,
        "enableProfilingAgent": false,
        "firstArg": "foo",
        "inputFile": "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt",
        "jobName": "wordcount-tuxdude-12345678",
        "numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads": 0,
        "output": "gs://BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/output",
        "pathValidatorClass": "com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DataflowPathValidator",
        "project": "PROJECT_NAME",
        "runner": "com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner",
        "secondArg": "bar",
        "stableUniqueNames": "WARNING",
        "stagerClass": "com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcsStager",
        "stagingLocation": "gs://BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/staging/",
        "streaming": false,
        "tempLocation": "gs://BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/staging/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### View all options as a table

```
$ gcloud dataflow jobs describe JOB_ID --full --format='flattened(environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options)'
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.apiRootUrl:                   https://dataflow.googleapis.com/
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.appName:                      WordCount
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.credentialFactoryClass:       com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcpCredentialFactory
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.dataflowEndpoint:
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.enableCloudDebugger:          False
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.enableProfilingAgent:         False
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.firstArg:                     foo
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.inputFile:                    gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.jobName:                      wordcount-tuxdude-12345678
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads: 0
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.output:                       gs://BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/output
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.pathValidatorClass:           com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DataflowPathValidator
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.project:                      PROJECT_NAME
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.runner:                       com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.secondArg:                    bar
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.stableUniqueNames:            WARNING
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.stagerClass:                  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcsStager
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.stagingLocation:              gs://BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/staging/
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.streaming:                    False
environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.tempLocation:                 gs://BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/staging/
```

### Get the value of just a single option

To get the value of just a single option named `--argName` (whose value BTW is `MY_ARG_VALUE`), you can do:

```
$ gcloud dataflow jobs describe JOB_ID --full --format='value(environment.sdkPipelineOptions.options.argName)'
MY_ARG_VALUE
```

### gcloud formatting

`gcloud` in general supports a wide range of formatting options in the output which is applicable to most `gcloud` commands which pull info from the server. You can read about them [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats).

Comment: wow it is right there in the documentation and I missed it... thanks!

Comment: It seems updated. The following worked for me now:

`gcloud dataflow jobs describe JOB_ID --full --format='json(environment.workerPools[0].metadata.sdk_pipeline_options)'`